# Subsetting a custom S4 class using the "subset" function within another function

Tags: r, methods, subset, environment, r-s4

I'm trying to define a `subset` method for my custom S4 class. While subsetting works as intended when I provide the subsetting critearia directly to `subset`, the method fails whenever I call it within another function, where the subsetting criteria is passed on to `subset` from that function.

The S4 class `myClass` consists of a single `data.frame`:

```r
# Define class
setClass("myClass", slots = c(data = "data.frame"))

# Initiate a myClass object
dat <- new("myClass", data = data.frame(Letter = c("A", "A", "B"), Number = c(1, 2, 3)))
```

To be able to subset the class based on the content of the `data.frame` in the slot `data`, I defined the following `subset`method:

```r
setMethod("subset", signature(x = "myClass"), function(x, ...) {
  x@data <- subset(x@data, ...)
  return(x)
})
```

The method works as expected when called as follows:

```r
# Assume we only want to retain entries containing the letter "A"
whichletter <- "A"

# Subset (does work)
subset(dat, Letter %in% whichletter)
```

```
An object of class "myClass"
Slot "data":
  Letter Number
1      A      1
2      A      2
```

However, when I try to run `subset` within another function, where the subset criteria is provided through that function's arguments, the subsetting won't work:

```
# Random function that takes a letter `let`as argument
randomFunction <- function(object, let) {
  object_subsetted <- subset(object, Letter %in% let)
  return(object_subsetted)
}

# Subset (does not work)
randomFunction(object = dat, let = whichletter)
```

```
Error in Letter %in% let: object 'let' not found
```

This appears to be an issue with environments but I can't figure out what exactly is going wrong. Does anyone have a suggestion how to avoid this error?

Comment: Notice that `subset(dat@data, Letter %in% whichletter)` works standalone as well, because `@data` is a plain old `data.frame` .   Might be easier in the long run to "rebuild"  your `x`  .

Comment: It will work if you define `setMethod` *inside* your user defined function. See this [informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33327891/1422451) about parent environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset) and [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#subset) which together seem to answer my question. The issue is unrelated to the use of S4 classes, but caused by how `subset` scopes variables. Initially, my definition of `subset` was looking for `let` inside the `x@data`object. By specifically defining to evaluate the expression in the scope of `x@data` but allowing to expand the scope to the `parent.frame()` (to which the variable `let`belongs to) solves the error and allows me to subset as desired.

Here is the full code:

```r
# Define class
setClass("myClass", slots = c(data = "data.frame"))

# Initiate a myClass object
dat <- new("myClass", data = data.frame(Letter = c("A", "A", "B"), Number = c(1, 2, 3)))

# Define a subset method
setMethod("subset", signature(x = "myClass"), function(x, ...) {
  condition <- substitute(...)
  indices <- eval(condition, x@data, parent.frame())
  x@data <- x@data[indices, ]
  return(x)
})

# Suppose we want to subset to only retain entries with "A"
whichletter <- "A"

# What if we have a function that should pass the subsetting value to the subset
# function?
randomFunction <- function(object, let) {
  object_subsetted <- subset(object, Letter %in% let)
  return(object_subsetted)
}

# Test it (works now)
randomFunction(object = dat, let = "A")
randomFunction(object = dat, let = "B")
```

```
An object of class "myClass"
Slot "data":
  Letter Number
1      A      1
2      A      2

An object of class "myClass"
Slot "data":
  Letter Number
3      B      3
```

However, as highlighted by @JDL it's probably wiser to define a `[` method instead.

Comment: Hey, I commented a recommendation to stick with `[` first!   Joking.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have alluded to, there are problems caused by `subset.data.frame` using non-standard evaluation on its argument. You can't use NSE on an argument which is part of a signature, since it is evaluated during method dispatch.

The help page for `subset` also says:

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like `[`, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument `subset` can have unanticipated consequences.

It may be better to write an appropriate method for `[`, and rely on `subset.default` which is defined as `x[subset & !is.na(subset)]`.

Comment: The argument that requires NSE (argument name `subset`) was never a part of the signature for function `subset`. Try `implicitGeneric("subset")`, you're gonna see `Methods may be defined for arguments: x`. So, S4 dispatch only evaluate `x` to get its class of `data.frame`, and never evaluate the argument `subset`. Therefore NSE works as normal.

Comment: Write a S4 method for `[` won't satisfy OP's need of NSE because running `implicitGeneric("[")`, you're gonna see `Methods may be defined for arguments: x, i, j, drop`, so argument `i` will be evaluated for S4 dispatch. Redefining the generic of `[` is not possible as running `setGeneric("[", signature = "x")` results in `Error in setGeneric("[", signature = "x") : 
  ‘[’ dispatches internally;  methods can be defined, but the generic function is implicit, and cannot be changed.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is part of the answer.  I find this strange  but clearly mucking with the unnamed arguments allow `eval` when called from `subset` to work as desired.

Inside debug mode, I entered two commands. Here are the results:

```
Browse[2]> subset(object@data,Letter %in% let, envir='CurrentEnvironment')
  Letter Number
1      A      1
2      A      2
Warning message:
In subset.data.frame(object@data, Letter %in% let, envir = "CurrentEnvironment") :
 extra argument ‘envir’ will be disregarded 
Browse[2]> subset(object, Letter %in% let)
Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'let' not found
```

I did this because I ran `traceback` when your function failed:

```
Rgames> randomFunction(object = dat, let = whichletter)
Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'let' not found
Rgames> traceback()
9: Letter %in% let
8: eval(e, x, parent.frame())
7: eval(e, x, parent.frame())
6: subset.data.frame(x@data, ...)
5: subset(x@data, ...)
4: subset(x@data, ...) at #2
3: subset(object, Letter %in% let)
2: subset(object, Letter %in% let) at #4
1: randomFunction(object = dat, let = whichletter)
```

So this means that somehow `subset.data.frame` is not properly passing `let` to the `eval` call -- or that maybe you need to pass an arg like

`subset(object, Letter %in% let, parent.frame(2))`

I haven't tested that; I'll let folks who are much more familiar with environment passing than I comment further. My guess is that the method `subset.data.frame` isn't "happy" with passing extra arguments?

Answer (score 0):

OP's answer is basically defining a brand new calculation based on `subset.data.frame`. The following approach focus on the non-standard evaluation (NSE) aspect and use the normal S4 dispatching mechanism to reuse existing `subset` function:

```r
# Same as OP
setClass("myClass", slots = c(data = "data.frame"))
dat <- new("myClass", data = data.frame(Letter = c("A", "A", "B"), Number = c(1, 2, 3)))
setMethod("subset", signature(x = "myClass"), function(x, ...) {
    x@data <- subset(x@data, ...)
    return(x)
})

# Use substitute, bquote or other means to construct the call then evaluate
randomFunction <- function(object, let) {
    ee <- substitute(subset(object, Letter %in% let))
    # ee <- bquote(subset(object, Letter %in% .(let)))
    
    print(deparse(ee))
    object_subsetted <- eval(ee)
    return(object_subsetted)
}

whichletter <- "A"
randomFunction(object = dat, let = whichletter) # For ee <- substitute(subset(object, Letter %in% let))
[1] "subset(dat, Letter %in% whichletter)"
An object of class "myClass"
Slot "data":
  Letter Number
1      A      1
2      A      2

randomFunction(object = dat, let = whichletter) # For ee <- bquote(subset(object, Letter %in% .(let)))
[1] "subset(object, Letter %in% \"A\")"
An object of class "myClass"
Slot "data":
  Letter Number
1      A      1
2      A      2
```

The problem you encountered with `subset` here was discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9863081/9454926)